# Any efficiency difference between using pipeline and directly using InputObject parameter?

Tags: powershell

Here is an example, I have a remote server named "s1" and I want to kill the processes of calc, notepad, winword in it.

I may have two ways to do this,

1. Using pipeline

`Get-Process -computername s1 -name "calc", "notepad", "winword" | Stop-Process`

2. Using InputObject parameter

`$processes = Get-Process -computername s1 -name "calc", "notepad", "winword"
Stop-Process -InputObject $processes`

IMO, I think the second way is much better than the first one.

It's said the pipeline in PowerShell actually passes object one by one to the following Cmdlet. In this case, Stop-Process needs to communicate with the remote computer "s1" **many times** and kills those processes one by one.

By contrast, with the second way, I guess Stop-Process will just communicate the remote computer "s1" **once** and complete the operation at one shot.

Do I understand this correctly?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: It confuses me too. The appropriate usage is to always pipe into the command. From what I can gather. -inputobject will sort of combine all the items as one, thus confusing the system. Some cmdlets may handle it better. I have never found a need to use it. Also it adds a step to your cmd. Putting output into a variable. And then into your command rather than just putting it straight into the command (at least most the time) also variables are snapshots. If you try to close an aged variable via stop-process you may kill the wrong process. Etc...

Comment: Also stop process can just take a name parameter saving more steps. `Stop-Process -computername s1 -name "calc", "notepad", "winword"`

Comment: Another option is invoke-command you can send the command as one and it will perform the whole thing at once. Becareful though. By default invoke-command builds a profile on any machine you use it on. So change the defaults via pssessionoptions

Comment: @RobertCotterman: `Stop-Process` doesn't have a `-ComputerName` parameter.

Comment: Ah dangit. My bad. I apologize. Thanks for the clarification. I am still in shock how you memorize all this stuff. Considering it prefers the id tag over name, it's smart not to as it would kill the wrong programs

Comment: No worries, @RobertCotterman - and I hadn't memorized that fact, I simply tried it out. Personally, I find the asymmetry between `Get-Process` targeting names by default and `Stop-Process` targeting IDs frustrating - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6551

Comment: I am sorry that it's not a good example.

Comment: I've added more general `-InputObject` vs. pipeline information to my answer; cc @RobertCotterman.

Answer (score 3):

As for the **remoting aspect**:

You should choose a different approach altogether: **run entire pipeline remotely, using `Invoke-Command`**:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName s1 { 
  Get-Process -Name 'calc', 'notepad', 'winword' | Stop-Process
}
```

Note, however, that `Invoke-Command` (PSv3+) requires *PowerShell remoting* to be configured on the target machine (see [`Get-Help about_Remote_FAQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq)), whereas the `Get-Process` cmdlet uses a different, obsolescent form of remoting.

In fact, when I tried your approach between two v5.1 machines, the locally run `Stop-Process` command that tried to operate on remote process objects *failed*, with the following error:

```
Cannot stop process "<name>" because of the following error:
Feature is not supported for remote machines.
```

Generally, the best approach is to **perform as much processing as possible remotely and only transfer the results to the local machine**.

---

As for the more **general aspect of pipeline input vs. input via `-InputObject`**:

**Use of `-InputObject` for passing a collection (`Get-Foo -InputObject $collection`) is definitely faster** than sending that collection through the pipeline (`$collection | Get-Foo`), but note that it **requires the entire input collection to be loaded into memory *as a whole*, *up front***, which potentially negates a key benefit of the pipeline: memory throttling.

Note that **use of `-InputObject` is often *not* a viable alternative to pipeline input**, because many cmdlets *do not enumerate* collections you pass to `-InputObject` (compare `1, 2 | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }` to `ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } -InputObject 1, 2`); typically, this happens accidentally, with `-InputObject` declarations that aren't *arrays*, but sometimes it is by design: the `Get-Member` cmdlet purposely doesn't enumerate a collection passed to `-InputObject`, because it then inspects the *collection's* type, not that of its elements. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) for background information.

Also note that if there are further pipeline segments (`Get-Foo -InputObject ... | ...`), then streaming (one-by-one processing) again happens *on output*.

You can **speed up item-by-item processing by using a `foreach` *statement*** (`foreach ($elem in $collection) { ... }`) in lieu of the pipeline, but that is only effective **if you can avoid cmdlet calls in the loop body**.
As with `-InputObject`, however, this **requires the entire input collection  to be loaded into memory *as a whole*, *up front***

---

A performance comparison with 10,000 input objects, averaged across 100 runs, using [`Time-Command`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27):

```
$collection = 1..10000
Time-Command -Count 100 { $collection | Write-Output }, 
                        { Write-Output -InputObject $collection },
                        { foreach ($o in $collection) { $o } }
```

Sample timings (Windows PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10, single-core VM):

```
Command                               Secs (100-run avg.) TimeSpan         Factor
-------                               ------------------- --------         ------
foreach ($o in $collection) { $o }    0.010               00:00:00.0103421 1.00
Write-Output -InputObject $collection 0.015               00:00:00.0152200 1.47
$collection | Write-Output            0.108               00:00:00.1076183 10.41
```

- `foreach` is fastest (note how *implicit* output is relied on in the loop body: if a `Write-Output` call had been used, this would have been by far the slowest solution), with `-InputObject` performance not far behind; interestingly, the roles seem to be *reversed* in PowerShell *Core*.
- Providing input via the pipeline was about 10 times slower.

However, note that the factors vary with the size of the input collection (and, possibly, your hardware).

Comment: This is sort of misleading. For your tasks at the end. Foreach is definitely faster. But that's due to the minimal time needed to call a variable. If you're using a foreach to iterate for a cmdlet that takes a while to start up, you can have it much worse off. As the cmdlet starts, runs it's needs, and exits. Rather than just looping through it's self. A great example is the dsinternals cmdlet (not std) get-addbaccount. I ran 60,000 accounts through it via a loop. And it took 72 hours. Where as just asking it to dump every account all at once takes about 5 mins for the same amount of accounts

Comment: @RobertCotterman: Note the following parts in the answer: "that is only effective if you can avoid cmdlet calls in the loop body" and "note how implicit output is relied on in the loop body: if a Write-Output call had been used, this would have been by far the slowest solution". So, which part is misleading?

Comment: Considering his goal is to call a cmdlet. But I suppose I let my tired brain not read enough.